# What calculation is happening in this Ruby expression: 5 << 7?

Tags: ruby

How does shovel operator between two integers result in the returned value?

```
irb(main):001:0> 5 << 7
=> 640
```

Comment: This is documented and easily found. Look at the http://ruby-doc.org/ main page, click the [Core API](http://ruby-doc.org/core) link, then use your browser to search for `<<`. You can figure it out easily from there.

Comment: It would be nice to tell us what specific part of the documentation you didn't understand, so that the Ruby developers can improve the documentation.

Comment: I first tried searching for '<<' in the search box at the top of the ruby-doc page but came up empty. Then I looked through the Integer and Numeric class pages for the '<<' method and came up empty. At the time, I never thought to do a browser search for '<<' on the core page to search through every single Ruby method in the core library. I learned my lesson.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bitwise shift:

```
640 = 5 * (2^7)
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to write this correctly in code as `5 * 2**7 #=> 640`.

Answer (score 8):

This is a left shift operator, where you can see it more easily demonstrated with binary notation:

```
 5 << 7
 # => 640
 5.to_s(2)
 # => "101"
 (5 << 7).to_s(2)
 # => "1010000000"
```

Notice the additional 7 `0` bits.